# Help me my first test

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have created a Hello World program and I am new to C#, My program will print 100 words like that as follow

```
public static void Main(/*I forgot arguments*/)
{
   string []s=new string [100];
   foreach(string ss in s)
   {
      ss="Hello World";
      Console.WriteLine("{0}\n",ss);      
   }
}
```

Could you show me  step-by-step how to create a test for this program ? Does it need one ? I don't have an image of how testers do the test. Sorry I am stupid.

I think I have tried my best, no one ever find I find it unworthy to me not to get any help ? I don't need the class because I forgot the class long ago after the accident.

Comment: Are you referring to unit testing or do you just want to 'run' this program? Your not stupid if you picked up C# as a language although it does help if you know a 'guru' to help you get going but there are plenty of tutorials on-line. Best way is just to get stuck in.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I notice that you assign a value to 'ss' every time you loop. If you do that, there is not really a point to iterating over the array. You probably want to assign values to the strings in the array before you start the 'foreach' loop.

Comment: Do you need to iterate an array like that, is there a reason for it? Would a for loop not be more appropriate?

Comment: I saw a *big fat* down there in C++ already, theere is no way for other games on fame. Block my acc, or ban me to hide, this happened for years and I ///never\\\ forget. He is such an shameful arshole in programming community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't (or - you shouldn't) test `void` methods. You are testing the output of the method - which Main does not have. Second thought: you cannot mock (simulate) an `Console` object. Read some tutorials about *mock* and *mocking*.

Sample method with sample test could look similar to this:

```
public class SimpleCalculator
{
    public int SumTwoNumbers(int number1, int number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_SimpleCalculator_SumTwoNumbers_CorrectValues()
    {
        // Arrange
        SimpleCalculator calc = new SimpleCalculator();

        // Act
        int result = calc.SumTwoNumbers(5, 2);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(7, result);
    }
}
```

Hope this helped a little.

Comment: Hello, that is a very understandable example, thank you, I have heard that test can be classified into many type, phylosophically (imperative, nonimpererative, etc ) What are they, how are they going to help in real test like this ? I bet they are just there for fun to underlying programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a test for this? What would you be testing for? Instead of how to test the code I'd be looking at how you can make it better.

Have a look at the Main below.

```
public static void Main(/*I forgot arguments*/)
{   
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)   
    {      
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");         
    }
}
```

Note, you don't use the array you create so there is no need to create it. Use a for loop when you know exactly how many times you need to loop. Also, there is no to format your string if you are not concating it with other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Flush the above code to a method than having it in the main. Then refer to some unit test cases documents (If unit testing is what your looking for) here http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.5.10

Comment: Thank you, what is the difference between a test case and test suit ?

Comment: suit means its a collection whole lot of cases grouped. Case is just a single entity.